# Codeigniter load model in controller - 500 erorr

Tags: codeigniter, model

This is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Order extends CI_Controller {

public function index($id=-1) {
  $this->load->model('order');
}
}
```

When i try to open the corresponding url i get Error 500. The strange thing is that i load the model the same way on another controller without a problem.

Here goes the route and the model just in case:

**Route:**

```
$route['order/(:num)'] = "order/index/$1";
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
    class Order extends CI_Model {

        var $fullname = '';
        var $email = '';
        var $address = '';
        var $phone = '';
        var $notes = '';
        var $facebook = '';
        //var $canvases = '';

        var $admin_notes = '';
        var $status = '';

        var $id = '';
        var $date = '';
        var $price = '';

        //var $emailStatus_recivedOrder = '';
        //var $emailStatus_sendedOrder = '';
        //var $emailStatus_askFeedback = '';

        function __construct() {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function get($search_query='', $per_page=5, $skip=0) {

            if($search_query != '') {
                $this->db->or_where('id', $search_query);
                $this->db->or_where('email', $search_query);
                $this->db->or_where('fullname', $search_query);
                $this->db->or_where('phone', $search_query);
            }

            $query = $this->db->get('entries', $per_page, $skip);
            return $query->result();
        }

        function count_all($search_query='') {
            if($search_query != '') {
                $this->db->or_where('id', $search_query);
                $this->db->or_where('email', $search_query);
                $this->db->or_where('fullname', $search_query);
                $this->db->or_where('phone', $search_query);
            }

            $this->db->from('entries');
            return $this->db->count_all_results();
        }

        function get_by_id($id) {
            return $this->db->get_where('entries', array('id' => $id), 1);
        }

        function get_active_orders_count() {
            $this->db->where('status', '1');
            $this->db->from('entries');
            return $this->db->count_all_results();
        }

        function insert_entry() {
            $this->fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
            $this->email = $this->input->post('email');
            $this->address = $this->input->post('address');

            $this->phone = $this->input->post('phone');

            $this->facebook = $this->input->post('facebook');

            $this->notes = $this->input->post('notes');
            $this->admin_notes = $this->input->post('admin_notes');
            $this->status = $this->input->post('status');

            $this->date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $this->db->insert('entries', $this);
        }

        function update_entry() {
            $this->admin_notes = $this->input->post('admin_notes');

            $this->db->update('entries', $this, array('id' => $this->input->post('admin_notes')));
        }
    }
```

The error is:
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346

Comment: can you see what exactly is the error? do you have a log file?

Comment: no, how to turn it on?

Comment: are you working on a local server or a hosted one?

Comment: local server, but i'm not so into development. I'm mainly responsible for design and frontend dev.

Comment: allright when your on a local server go to your php directory find php.ini and change this lines with this error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: in your php.ini file*

Comment: don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346

Comment: see my answer. that has to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name your controller and model the same.
give them a different name and the problem should be fixed. So something like

### Controller

```
class Order extends CI_Controller{ ... }
```

### Model

```
class Order_model extends CI_Model{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objected oriented programming no two class can have the same name. As of codeigniter Controllers, Models are all classes. So, it is good practice to name your controller as ABC_Controller and model as ABC_Model to avoid class name conflict.

Controller

```
class ABC_Controller extends CI_Controller { .. }
```

Model

```
class ABC_Model extends CI_Model { .. }
```

Comment: It might be useless to you @Kees Sonnema. but not to questioner.